# opencv - TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, opencv

I recently installed `opencv` and executed `npm install`.

After doing that, I was given some sample code to see if it works, but it does not work, and I don't know why. Maybe I installed it incorrectly, I am a newbie to this. Here is the code:

```
cv.readImage("./examples/files/mona.png", function(err, im){
  im.detectObject(cv.FACE_CASCADE, {}, function(err, faces){
    for (var i=0;i<faces.length; i++){
      var x = faces[i]
      im.ellipse(x.x + x.width/2, x.y + x.height/2, x.width/2, x.height/2);
    }
    im.save('./out.jpg');
  });
})
```

Comment: I believe your `faces` object is undefined (#noSh!t) because you might have an error in the `err` object from the callback. Try printing that `err` in the console to see what it gives you. console.error(err);

Comment: I assume your file path is not correct `./examples/files/mona.png`, it was an example path with code, fix it as per your directory structure. try to `console.log(err);` after firs line

Comment: The only place where `length` is used, is in the loop, so `faces` clearly isn't what you think it is.

Comment: The path is correct, we checked that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install it by "npm install opencv --save" But since there is no dependency issue so you installed it right. Try doing console.log(faces) because it is giving null as result in faces that's why length is undefined.
Also make sure the image at that path you are giving "./examples/files/mona.png" do exist.

Comment: Ok so I tried the `npm install opencv --sav`. I get two errors: node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403) and node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre built binaries are not found. But when using `build-from-source`, it worked. Please any help would be appreciated. @ Asim Raja

Comment: I tried npm install opencv --save it worked on me, what exactly do you want to do? Besides have you hecked your path "./examples/files/mona.png"? Does "mona.png" exists?

Comment: I added `var faces` to the code. `console.log(faces) output was undefined` and `console.log(err) is null`

Comment: IS THE PICTURE OF MONA in the path "./examples/files/mona.png"?

Comment: yes it worked but I had to add `var faces`. Is that suppose to happen. cuz now it works

Comment: And faces is undefined still?

Comment: yes but the code works now with `var faces`. don't know if thats a problem. the output is suppose to be a red circle over mona lisa's face

Comment: To do that you have to use matrices and create readstream to get image produced by the opencv, see this whole documentation for further guidance 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv